# Do I have to worry about "error: superfluous RAID member"?

Tags: grub2, raid, mdadm

When running `update-grub` on the newly installed Ubuntu 12.04 with an older software RAID (md), I get:

```
error: superfluous RAID member (5 found).
error: superfluous RAID member (5 found).
Generating grub.cfg ...
error: superfluous RAID member (5 found).
error: superfluous RAID member (5 found).
error: superfluous RAID member (5 found).
error: superfluous RAID member (5 found).
error: superfluous RAID member (5 found).
error: superfluous RAID member (5 found).
error: superfluous RAID member (5 found).
error: superfluous RAID member (5 found).
error: superfluous RAID member (5 found).
error: superfluous RAID member (5 found).
error: superfluous RAID member (5 found).
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic
error: superfluous RAID member (5 found).
error: superfluous RAID member (5 found).
error: superfluous RAID member (5 found).
error: superfluous RAID member (5 found).
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-23-generic
error: superfluous RAID member (5 found).
error: superfluous RAID member (5 found).
error: superfluous RAID member (5 found).
error: superfluous RAID member (5 found).
error: superfluous RAID member (5 found).
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
error: superfluous RAID member (5 found).
error: superfluous RAID member (5 found).
error: superfluous RAID member (5 found).
error: superfluous RAID member (5 found).
error: superfluous RAID member (5 found).
Found Debian GNU/Linux (5.0.9) on /dev/sdb1
Found Debian GNU/Linux (5.0.9) on /dev/sdc1
done
```

I would be less worried if the message would say `warning: ...`, but since it says `error: ...` I'm wondering what the problem is.

```
# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md2 : active raid1 sdc1[1] sdb1[0]
      48829440 blocks [2/2] [UU]

md3 : active raid1 sdc2[1] sdb2[0]
      263739008 blocks [2/2] [UU]

md1 : active raid5 sdg1[3] sdf1[2] sde1[1] sdh1[0] sdi1[4] sdd1[5](S)
      1250274304 blocks level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [5/5] [UUUUU]

unused devices: <none>
```

Do I have to worry or is this harmless?

btw: disregard the mentioning of Debian 5.0.9, that was the previously installed system and is going to be overwritten. It's on `/dev/md2` actually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8330/6661) by [Fussy Salsify](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4595/fussy-salsify) this seems to be a [bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=610184) of update-grub script with spare device in one of the RAID arrays. As mentioned [here](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=610184) a patch has been applied and should come to Ubuntu at some time.

[Boyd Stephen Smith Jr.](http://groups.google.com/groups/profile?enc_user=abLSNRUAAACqz0q8GVe4MXvIkQw_xCpTv6ZVbJKGbokpZxwW7G4fAA) said he thinks this error report may be just cosmetic [here](http://groups.google.com/group/linux.debian.bugs.dist/browse_thread/thread/079f638bb8d57164?pli=1) and [Vladimir 'φ-coder/phcoder' Serbinenko](http://groups.google.com/groups/profile?enc_user=5MEpuxEAAAA1KcKBZAznoi4kOBei2IIBkdEasx1kiYTQavV7mdW13Q) submitted a [patch](http://groups.google.com/group/linux.debian.bugs.dist/attach/8b683e5ebc19616f/mdraid_skip_spares.diff?part=3&view=1) that seems to just change the error report to "spares aren't implemented".

Also there is a bug report at launchpad ([#816475](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/816475)) and a possible [workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/816475/comments/3) that involves changing the partitioning. The importance of this bug is undecided at launchpad but looks like it caused some real problem to [Björn Tillenius](https://launchpad.net/~bjornt) that could not upgrade/install grub. So looks like you should be careful.

Comment: Thanks @desgua, the most important part of the question is, whether I need to worry (e.g. that my system becomes unbootable) due to the errors. Unfortunately even sifting over the bug report you linked, there seems to be no conclusive and/or authoritative statement as to whether I have to worry about it or not. +1 for the pointers already :)

Comment: I have found some more info ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error on ubuntu 12.04 both during upgrade-grub and briefly upon booting the PC but it was due to a misconfiguration on my side:

I had two partitions on two disks paired with mdadm using RAID1. After one disk crashed I replaced it and added a new one but at some point while entering the commands to add the partitions (`mdadm --manage /dev/md... -a /dev/sd...`) I erroneously added the whole disk (/dev/**sdb**) instead of the partition (/dev/**sdb1**) as part of /dev/md1. I removed the whole disk and correctly added the partition and things were looking just fine at /proc/mdstat so I thought I was over.

However upon rebooting "error: superfluous RAID member (2 found)." was appearing briefly on my screen and the raid array was not reconstructed with my the partitions of the new disk.

I had to zero-out the superblock of /dev/sdb (the disk) with `mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdb` to fix it which also got rig of the "error: superfluous RAID member (2 found)." both from startup and update-grub.